# Managing multiple RenderWindow's in sfml

Tags: c++, window, render, sfml

I seem to be having a bit of trouble when managing multiple windows in SFML C++. When I try to manage multiple windows, they both open correctly and I can interact in the larger one, however, the smaller one, which upon creation is overlapping the larger window, I can not interact with until I move the large window away. An image is below to help with the visual. Also below is the main loop for my code.

[image: To help the visual, "SFML - F1 Menu" is the window not responding to interaction.]

The main loop of the code is as follows:

```
while (MainWin.isOpen() || F1Menu.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event Event;
    if (MainWin.pollEvent(Event))
    {
        switch (Event.type)
        {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                MainWin.close();
                if (F1Menu.isOpen())
                    F1Menu.close();
            break;

            case sf::Event::Resized:
                MainView.reset(sf::FloatRect(0.f, 0.f, (MainWin.getSize().x*0.9f), (MainWin.getSize().y*0.9)));
                MainWin.setView(MainView);
            break;

            case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                if (Event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::F1)
                    F1Menu.create(sf::VideoMode(200, 500), "SFML 2D - F1 Menu");
                else if (Event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
                {
                    MainWin.close();
                    if (F1Menu.isOpen())
                        F1Menu.close();
                }
            break;
        }
    }

    if (F1Menu.pollEvent(Event))
    {
        switch (Event.type)
        {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                F1Menu.close();
            break;

            case sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased:
                if (Event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
                    if (LMButton.mouseIn(F1Menu))
                        LoadMap("MapA.dat");
            break;

            case sf::Event::MouseMoved:
                if (LMButton.mouseIn(F1Menu))
                    LMButton.setColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
                else
                    LMButton.setColor(sf::Color::White);
            break;
        }
    }

    moveClock.restart();
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
    {
        player.move(0, -4 * time);
        player.setDirection(sfm::Direction::Up);
    }

    else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
    {
        player.move(0, 4 * time);
        player.setDirection(sfm::Direction::Down);
    }

    else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
    {
        player.move(-4 * time, 0);
        player.setDirection(sfm::Direction::Left);
    }

    else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
    {
        player.move(4 * time, 0);
        player.setDirection(sfm::Direction::Right);
    }

    if (F1Menu.isOpen())
    {
        F1Menu.clear();
        F1Menu.draw(LMButton);
        F1Menu.display();
    }

    if (MainWin.isOpen())
    {
        MainWin.clear();
        if (SplashScreen.didAnimate)
            SplashScreen.Animate(MainWin, sfg::Animation::FadeIn);
        if (inMenu)
        {

        }
        if (isPlaying)
        {
            DrawMap(MainWin);
            MainWin.draw(player);
        }
        MainWin.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you creating your second window *inside* an event? that's usually a pretty bad idea, as you don't want to be calling tons of create calls for F1 EDIT: I see you're using `if` as opposed to the common practice of using a `while` to poll events. Is there a reason for this? This could be giving you some trouble later on

Comment: I will be adding a check for the F1 Menu, if it is already open, do not open it again, or instead close it. There is no specific reason for the `if`, I can change it to `while`. Do you have any ideas on the presented problem though?

Comment: Your event checking is fundamentally flawed to begin with. There can be multiple events per polling, using a `while` would allow you to pop off the top of the stack and continue to handle **all** events. You should fix your code and see if your problem is solved. Note that you should not be creating a window *inside* an event loop because you cannot guarante it will be called only once(unless you just nest it inside an if to check if window has not already been created)

Comment: Problem still exists. And nesting the window creation in an `if` was the idea all along

Answer (score 1):

In my knowledge, you aren't able to poll two separate windows with one `sf::Event` object. this is because when polling events, you are essentially **popping** off of the event stack and handling each one. The signature of pollEvent is

`bool pollEvent(sf::Event &event);`

note that there is no `const` qualifier here, because each processed event gets popped off the event stack. By the time you finish polling your main window there are no events left for your other window. This could be the cause of your window being unable to focus. Your second window should use it's own separate `sf::Event`

On a side note I would highly recommend encapsulating your data inside classes. You can find a great reference [here](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/wiki/Tutorial:-Manage-different-Screens) on how to go about doing so. It's great coding practice and helps minimize confusion when bug hunting

Comment: Already changed it to two events. I am in the process of adding everything to classes, trying to fix this first. EDIT: Already read supplied article, will be using it later.

Comment: @Reborn does two events not fix the issue?

Comment: Two events does nothing. Problem still exists.

Comment: @Reborn ok quick question then, does your second window focus when you click the *upper* part of the window? (near the title, not the body of the window)

Comment: No, it does not focus, but when dragging other window away, so the smaller one is no longer in front of it, I can then focus on the smaller window.

Comment: I'd recommend taking this to the SFML forums, i'm stumped on why that would happen. [link](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/)

Comment: Already tried that, no one has even attempted to answer, it's been about 2 days.

Comment: @Reborn want to provide me a link to the project? I'll run it on my machine and see what the problem is

Comment: I'd prefer not to, but since at this point I really just need this fixed, I will message it to you. Keep in mind there is test code, and nothing is organized in there.

Comment: After moving the executable to a second device and running it, it seems to not have a problem.

Comment: @Reborn I just copy pasted your code and reproduced it in my environment. I'll see if I can find a fix

Comment: @SyntacticFructose: one `sf::Event` is perfectly fine!

Comment: @SyntacticFructose Find anything?